# Failed: Cannot read property 'cartblock' of undefined

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm new to protractor using javascript, I created a simple script that calls data from another js file.

I have a file called jsobjectdemo.js that contains

```
<pre>
this.productnames = element.all(by.tagName("app-card")); 
this.cartblock = element(by.css("h4 a"));
this.addcartbutton = element(by.css("button[class='btn btn-info']"));
</pre>
```

And another file called jscalldemo.js

```
var cart = require('./jsobjectdemo.js');

    function addCart(productname){

        cart.productnames.each(function(item){
            cart.cartblock.getText().then(function(text){
                if (text==productname){
                    cart.addcartbutton.click();
                }
            })
        })
        }
```

When i ran the script, it returns an error

```
Message:
  Failed: Cannot read property 'cartblock' of undefined
Stack:
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'cartblock' of undefined
      at D:\Trainings\Protractor\protractor-workspace\Protractor\jscalldemo.js:8:14
```

Comment: Still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
Const loc = {
productnames = element.all(by.tagName("app-card")), cartblock = element(by.css("h4 a")), addcartbutton = element(by.css("button[class='btn btn-info']"))
}
exports.cart = loc;
```

Change your jsobjectdemo.js to the above.

And in your jscalldemo.js

```
Const cart = require('./jsobjectdemo.js').cart;
```

Now you can use `cart.cartblock` in jscalldemo.js